# Placing HTML in right place

Tags: html, css

Sup guys. I can't make bew page with blocks to be in the same way as they are meant to be. I have problem with this high block, called "Bags". I tried flex-box, I tried float. Maybe someone can help me in placing everything in the way it was meant to be.

```css
figcaption
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
    height: 41px;
 bottom: 0px;
 padding-top: 13px;
 padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 21.333px;
    font-family: "SegoeUIBold";
    opacity: 0.8; 
    background-color: #FFF;
}

figure
{
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
      <figure class="huge">
        <img src="img/greenTshirt.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>T-Shirts</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="normal">
        <img src="img/cards.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Cards</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="normal">
        <img src="img/pens.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Pens &amp; Pencils</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="wide">
        <img src="img/notebooks.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Notebooks</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="normal">
        <img src="img/toys.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Toys</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="high">
        <img src="img/bags.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Bags</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="normal">
        <img src="img/scrum.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Scrum cards</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="normal">
        <img src="img/magnets.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Magnets</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="big">
        <img src="img/redCaps.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Caps</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="normal">
        <img src="img/magnets.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Magnets</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="normal">
        <img src="img/pens.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Pens &amp; Pencils</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="normal">
        <img src="img/toys.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Toys</figcaption>
      </figure>
  </main>
```

Images:
[Model](http://cs625717.vk.me/v625717845/48895/dA678TkD6zY.jpg)

[Result](http://cs625717.vk.me/v625717845/4889f/U8yvn-f_rCc.jpg)

Comment: I think it would be easier to use a plugin for this, something like **[masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com)**

Comment: Indeed. Not even flexbox can do that **and** maintain the structure you have. That's why Masonry is so popular.

Comment: @RamisWachtler thanks, but masonry put everything in such strange order and with so big spaces between blocks that I'm not sure if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below instead the one you are trying.

CSS:

```
figcaption {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 41px;
            bottom: 0px;
            padding-top: 13px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            font-size: 21.333px;
            font-family: "SegoeUIBold";
            opacity: 0.8;
            background-color: #FFF;
        }

        figure {
            position: relative;
            padding: 5em;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<main>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/greenTshirt.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>T-Shirts</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/cards.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Cards</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/pens.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Pens &amp; Pencils</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/notebooks.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Notebooks</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/toys.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Toys</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/bags.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Bags</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/scrum.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Scrum cards</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/magnets.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Magnets</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/redCaps.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Caps</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/magnets.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Magnets</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/pens.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Pens &amp; Pencils</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/toys.png" alt="">
            <figcaption>Toys</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </main>
```

and if you want to increase the size of the image, you can do it and then increase the padding in the css.